# find contact us pages using google importxml xpath

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to pull links to contact pages from a list of urls in column B. I have tried the following but I get an error:

```
=IMPORTXML(B10,"//a[contains('contact')]/@href")
```

I want to be able to get href value for every a element that has anchor text containing the word "contact".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be so kind and show the contents of the cell `B10` (alternatively, show one of the URLs)? And show the error message, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the URL you import, I can only comment on the XPath expression. Your expression is not valid, `contains()` always takes two arguments. Use

```
=IMPORTXML(B10,"//a[contains(.,'contact')]/@href")
```

If that does not give the expected result, you have to tell us the URL of the document you are importing.

Comment: Can you help with this URL? http://www.clarksonuniversity.org/admissions/undergrad_admissions/costs/scholarships/first.html
I am trying to extract the full url for the contact us page on the bottom. This page happens to use relative urls in the href code which further complicate matters.

Comment: @RayA Usually, people do not unaccept answers just to ask a follow-up question. For this specific page, the `C` should be uppercase: `//a[contains(.,'Contact')]/@href`. No, XPath cannot help you to expand relative links because the URL is nowhere in the document and invisible to the XPath engine. You'd have to use a full-flegded programming language.