# extract urls of zoominfo which contains ID

Tags: xml, google-sheets

using Importxml function in Googlespreadsheet on below task.

In Column A contains all www.zoominfo.com/p urls(few thousands) and in column B contains company IDs(few thousands).

Column A
http://www.zoominfo.com/p/

Column B
2059022647

Column C
=transpose(importxml(A1, "//a[contains(., '"&B1&"')]/@href"))

Result: #N/A (imported content is empty)

Column C has to extract http://www.zoominfo.com/p/Michael-Withers/-2059022647 url

So, Transpose function will extract all urls which contains IDs from columnB in horizontal.

Hope you understand what I am trying to extract.

Please let me know where I been making mistake.

Comment: can you share the results page your actually pulling from  - ive done this exact query with company pages - there also a few things with you syntax that are incorrect but i need to test the results before i can give you the proper answer in full

Comment: Actually, I want to pull results from http://www.zoominfo.com/p/[candidate name automatically pulled through xpath query]/2059022647.  This is what I am doing to extract. I do not know how many public profiles are their in each company through google/directly from zoominfo.  So, its like guess function method.  Let me know if you understand what I want to. I saw a query posted on stackoverflow. Here is the discuss on sample query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883226/find-contact-us-pages-using-google-importxml-xpath

Comment: oh, In that case, I cannot pull all profiles from same company. I thought that ID is unique for each company in zoominfo.com. Thanks Making me understand.

Answer (score 0):

your query is incorrect - the id at the end of the persons name is not the same id as the company id - so appending that would not be the correct profile.

for example a zoominfo profile for a person is zoominfo.com/p/my-name-here/-2071684546 and the company i work for is zoominfo.com/c/my-company-here/371802245.

The ids at the end is a static unique identifier - plus people change companies constantly so it would not make sense to keep the company id attached to the name url.

Comment: Hi Aurielle, Yes, I understand. There is a way which we can. Could you please post that xpath code for above query.

Comment: Here is the document with details for your request. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zn6NW1Ly7QMC0LBzEsIT7A99k5YjOK4MW-wQphS4bPs/pub?output=xlsx Let me know.

Comment: I made a sample spreadsheet for you - you said you have company ids already correct?